# How to add top and bottom padding to the html element?

Tags: html, css, padding

The height of ".stats-preview-card-component" is bigger than the height of my window, so the "HTML" element automatically increased its height, but the top and bottom part of the previously mentioned card end to end to the top and bottom part of the "HTML" element.

To add some more space between the card and the webpage I decided to add some padding to the top and bottom of the "html" element accordingly...

Padding works only if it is either on top or bottom, but not both at the same time!

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

html {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0a0c19;
  font: 400 15px Inter, sans-serif;
}


/* Screen readers only */

.visually-hidden:not(:focus, :active) {
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}

.stats-preview-card-component {
  height: 780px;
  width: 327px;
  background-color: rgb(28 26 56);
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="visually-hidden">Stats preview card component</h1>
</header>
<main class="stats-preview-card-component"></main>
```

Link to work: https://codepen.io/Rock-n-Roll-CRC/pen/PoyVzBb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add padding only to body element, delete padding property from html element. Also use height and width only for body element

```
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0a0c19;
  font: 400 15px Inter, sans-serif;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 


Why does this work though? What HTML element did wrong that it didn't work properly?

Comment: Padding and width-height properties for <html>. Normally the better option is to use CSS for <body>

Answer (score 0):

To add top and bottom padding to the html element, you can modify the existing CSS code as follows:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0; /* Add top and bottom padding */
}

/* Rest of the CSS code remains the same */
```

By setting `padding: 50px 0;`, you are adding 50 pixels of padding to the top and bottom of the html element. This will create space between the card and the webpage.

Make sure to place this code after the existing CSS code you provided. With this modification, both top and bottom padding will be applied simultaneously to the html element.

Comment: Doesn't work, my code already has "html {padding: 50px 0}".

Comment: Did you generate this using some tool like ChatGPT?